# Getting data from an autocomplete field to post when form is submitted

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I’m seeking some help with an autocomplete text field that I added to an existing data entry form.  I want the selected value to be posted back to the database when the form is submitted.
The form was built as a scaffold and then I added a new autocomplete text field using the instructions at https://joelc.io/dynamic-autocomplete-rails-6.
I had to make some modifications, but so far, so good.  The autocomplete field populates with data from my database, and the form works as expected.
What I want to do now is to have the autocomplete field replace or become one of the form fields so that the selected value is posted back to the database, and I don’t know how to do this, and I don’t mind doing the research, but I don’t know where to start.
I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.
My initial guess is that either the two fields can be combined into one where the listener code for the autocomplete function recognizes the field and it also gets posted when the form is submitted, or alternatively, the form field is hidden and the value is updated once a value is selected in the autocomplete field.
The autocomplete function has code in several places and I still have not wrapped my head around how it all works, but I’ve included the quickentry.js code which might be relevant, and the source of the 2 fields in the _quickentryform.html.erb partial.

```
      <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :PayTo %>
        <%= form.text_field :PayTo %>
      </div>

  <input type="search" placeholder="Enter payto..." data-behavior="autocomplete">
```

**This is the code from quickentry.js**

```
/*
Here, jQuery is telling the browser to: (1) wait until turbolinks finishes loading, (2) apply the easyAutocomplete method to all inputs where the data-behavior attribute equals autocomplete, (3) and pass it the data stored in the options variable.
*/

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  
  //console.log("Listener called");
  $input = $('*[data-behavior="autocomplete"]')

  var options = {
    url: function(phrase) {
      return "/quickentry/search.json?q=" + phrase;
    },
    getValue: "payto",
  };

  $input.easyAutocomplete(options);

});
```

5/30 - Adding some of the generated source code as an example - I trimmed out some fields to keep it shorter.  The 2 relevant fields are PayTo and the following autocomplete field.

Thanks again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Account Reconciliation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="uVmeTTbYqtuD8grruvnPgRTujDk9waoXuFfKZXSh2002JyT827AeTobcK82w3IADilRTtHNYjbxbf_8X_CVxDw" />
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.debug-f674dfbf9ba642b5bd0b7af42a29530b1811c4c9e5bb0ca12863bee4b4af3819.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
    <script src="/packs/js/application-a77022edd8841e243842.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Quick transaction entry form</h1>

<form action="/transactions" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="sRdVtu6qR1CfBqnIEAGccccS8Pvt1N8n5taGMGG8rtNZupv82CFfCOXYF1hIQoXiRyj35uGYEsh0ujkGM6_PZw" autocomplete="off" />

  <div class="field">
    <label for="transaction_AcctNum">Acctnum</label>
    <input type="number" name="transaction[AcctNum]" id="transaction_AcctNum" />
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="transaction_Amount">Amount</label>
    <input type="text" name="transaction[Amount]" id="transaction_Amount" />
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="transaction_PayTo">Payto</label>
    <input type="text" name="transaction[PayTo]" id="transaction_PayTo" />
  </div>

  <input type="search" placeholder="Enter name..." data-behavior="autocomplete">

  <div class="field">
    <label for="transaction_Description">Description</label>
    <input type="text" name="transaction[Description]" id="transaction_Description" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="transaction_Notes">Notes</label>
    <input type="text" name="transaction[Notes]" id="transaction_Notes" />
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create Transaction" data-disable-with="Create Transaction" />
  </div>
</form>

<a href="/transactions">Back</a>

  <script async nonce="" type="text/javascript" id="mini-profiler" src="/mini-profiler-resources/includes.js?v=35a79b300ab5afa978cb59af0b05e059" data-css-url="/mini-profiler-resources/includes.css?v=35a79b300ab5afa978cb59af0b05e059" data-version="35a79b300ab5afa978cb59af0b05e059" data-path="/mini-profiler-resources/" data-current-id="s6b24c933wlluqdver61" data-ids="s6b24c933wlluqdver61" data-horizontal-position="left" data-vertical-position="top" data-trivial="false" data-children="false" data-max-traces="20" data-controls="false" data-total-sql-count="false" data-authorized="true" data-toggle-shortcut="alt+p" data-start-hidden="false" data-collapse-results="true" data-html-container="body" data-hidden-custom-fields="" data-turbo-permanent="false"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be possible since a lot of things need to be installed including my database, but I'll try adding a trimmed version of the generated page source code. I'm guessing that someone has run into the same issue of trying to get an autocomplete field to post to the database.

Comment: Yes, I agree many have. I suspect that since your `input` element is missing a `name` attribute, it may not be passed along properly with your other form data. You might try that first unless the autocomplete value is put into another field.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Twisty - your suggestion led me to the answer.

I used the original `payto` field that was being stored, and looked up how to add other attributes, in this case since the jQuery code seemed to be looking for a specific `data-behaviour` attribute, adding that to the original field did the trick.
Thanks again for your help.  Much appreciated.

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :PayTo %>
    <%= form.search_field :PayTo, placeholder: "Enter name...", "data-behavior": "autocomplete" %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sorry about not capitalizing jQuery correctly.  However, I believe it would be less confusing to readers to either restore the original spelling of 'data-behavior' (or change the name of the attribute itself to 'data-behaviour') because regardless of the spelling, they need to match at both ends.